# How to debug a Scala SBT project in IntelliJ 13?

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, sbt

I have never tried using any sort of debugger with Scala and never tried debugging anything in IntelliJ Idea (while I have been using Idea to write Scala code). Now, as [the recent IntelliJ Idea 13 has gotten built-in SBT support](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2014/03/24/scala-and-play-plugins-update-in-intellij-idea-13-1/) I have tried to use this feature (instead of the old sbt-idea SBT plug-in way) to import an SBT project and this seems to work. But what I can't figure out is how to run and debug the program in this case. Of course I can use the conventional SBT command line way to build and run but isn't Idea supposed to have native ways for this now? The first window I've illustrated below that pops-up when I click Run-Debug or Run-Run suggests it is, as well as the second (the Project Structure window) which is called.

[image: Run/Debug Configurations window]

(note that the Run button is disabled (grayed) and never goes enabled whatever I do)

[image: Project Structure window]

Why does it complain about the SBT::scala-compiler-bundle:2.11.0 library not used by the way? How am I intended to use it? Isn't it the compiler/SBT/IDE who needs it?

Also, when I click Build - Make Project an Abnormal build process termination exception (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException) emerges:

`Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:73)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.(NioEventLoopGroup.java:72)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.(NioEventLoopGroup.java:58)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.main(BuildMain.java:77)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:128)`

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am using the latest stable Java, Scala, SBT, and Idea releases to this date.

Comment: I've seen the "SBT::scala-compiler-bundle:2.11.0" type error before...and it's usually when all my auto-complete stuff fails and the project stops building within IntellJ (yet still builds perfectly from the command line). In those cases I usually delete the .idea directory and reimport. IntellJ's Scala support is still horribly buggy. I haven't used the debugger but am interested in the answer to this as I use Scala+SBT+IntellJ on a daily basis.

Comment: Well, @djsumdog, simply deleting the .idea directory and reimporting as you have suggested seems to have solved the problem - building, running and debugging works now (so, I think this makes you eligible to post this suggestion as an answer and get it approved as a solution). But the "SBT::scala-compiler-bundle:2.11.0" error is still there. Perhaps the initial problem cause was the fact that the initial Idea settings (that wew there when I have imported the project for the first time) were bad (no JDK set, scala 2.10 chosen while the project is in 2.11 etc.))

Comment: I have also noticed that it never works once I import a new project, I always have to delete the `.idea` directory and reimport. Perhaps this takes place because Idea does some necessary downloads SBT itself does not or something like that. Another weird thing is that I always have to specify Scala 2.11 version in the project structure window once I import a project - Idea seems to ignore it being set in build.sbt and set it to 2.10 by default.

Answer (score 3):

If someone experiences similar things like e.g.:

- Autocompletion fails
- Inside "project structure" it complains about "scala-compiler-bundle is not used"
- some other weird stuff happens in the IDE

You can either do as suggested in a previous comment (maybe this helps in your case!) or you do what helped me..

What I did to create my project:

I created my basic project (using play 2.3 scala template) with the activator command. After that I imported the project (IDEA 13.1.4). Building the project from from the command line worked perfeclty while the project in my IDE went crazy.. (like I described above)

Solution:

Go to your "project structure" and remove one of the three modules IntelliJ configured on project import. It configures a "root" module containing all the necessary dependencies, a "root-build" module and a module named after your project. The solution is to remove the module which is named after your project and add the "scala-compiler-bundle" to your root module. After that my project worked totally fine inside IntelliJ.

I hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: I had similar problems, simply renaming re-created the Idea project (remove or rename .idea folder, then New project and point to the sbt file). Didn't find other way to get IDEA in sync.